# Tips for creating “Context Free Grammar”

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, lexical-analysis, formal-languages

I am new to CFG's,
Can someone give me tips in creating CFG that generates some language

For example

```
 L ={ w v w~ |v| is even }, where alphabet={a,b} and w~ is inverse of
 string w
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the language .. I want to build DFA to convert it

Comment: So, this is some class homework, you don't understand a word of it, so you typed it in here hoping we would do it for you instead? Yes?

Comment: No .. I have a test tomorrow and I can not resolve such a question .. Can you help me :)

Comment: Duplicate question posted here: [http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/tips-for-creating-context-free-grammar](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/tips-for-creating-context-free-grammar)